# How can I create an even distribution of objects with different weights (scheduling)?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, scheduling, distribution

Here is my problem in English:

- I've got several `WidgetContainer` objects.
- Each `WidgetContainer` will have at least one `Widget`.
- Each `WidgetContainer` wants to display one of its `Widgets` `n` amount of times per day.
- `Widgets` could be displayed on 'x' number of `Venues`.
- A `Widget` is displayed for exactly `t` seconds before the next scheduled `WidgetContainer's` `Widget` takes its place.
- If the entire day's is not filled up then nothing should be displayed during those times (ads should be evenly dispersed throughout the day `t` seconds at a time)

And here are the objects represented by pseudo code:

```
var WidgetContainers = [
   {
       DailyImpressionsRequired: 52, // should be split between Venues
       Widgets: ["one", "two"],
       Venues: ["here", "there"]
   },
   {
       DailyImpressionsRequired: 20,
       Widgets: ["foo"],
       Venues: ["here", "there", "everywhere"]
   },
   {
       DailyImpressionsRequired: 78,
       Widgets: ["bar", "bat", "heyhey!"],
       Venues: ["up", "down", "allAround"]
   }
];
var SecondsInADay = 86400;
var DisplayInterval = 30; // seconds
var TotalNumverOrVenues = /*eh, some calulations...*/;
var AvailableSlots = /*eh, some calulations...*/;
var SlotsNeeded = /*eh, some calulations...*/;
```

I need to find an efficient way of calculating an evenly distributed schedule for these objects. These "objects" are linq-to-sql objects so some linq suggestions would be nice

My idea right now is to flatten the `WidgetContainers` to their `Widgets`; dividing their `DailyImpressions` by the number of `Widgets`.

I could figure it out easily if there weren't multiple and differing Venues to take into account.

I have a feeling I just need to see someone else's perspective on the problem since I've been staring at is so long.

So, *any* help that could possibly point me in the right direction or provide some perspective on the problem, even if it is obvious, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So... are the DailyImpressions split between the venues, or per venue?

Comment: They would be split between venues. So if I needed 30 impressions and they had to display in 3 venues each venue would get 10. (don't you love my 1337 math skillz? =-)

Comment: Maybe if you could tell us what the right answers would be for your example, just to make sure people are understanding right - I think there would be 6 venues (only counting distinct?), available slots would be (seconds per day) * (distinct venues) / (display interval) = 17280, slots needed would be sum((distinct widgets) * (daily impressions required)) = 358?

Comment: +1 @Richard, Yes, that looks right. Although the slots needed would be `sum( (daily impressions required) ) = 150`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on that lot, if I've understood, this should give you correct answers:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<WidgetContainer> data = new List<WidgetContainer>();

            data.Add(new WidgetContainer {
                Widgets = new List<String> {"one","two"},
                Venues = new List<String>{"here","there"},
                DailyImpressionsRequired=52});

            data.Add(new WidgetContainer {
                Widgets = new List<String> {"foo"},
                Venues = new List<String>{"here","there","everywhere"},
                DailyImpressionsRequired=20});

            data.Add(new WidgetContainer {
                Widgets = new List<String> {"bar","bat", "heyhey!"},
                Venues = new List<String>{"up","down", "allAround"},
                DailyImpressionsRequired=78});

            var SecondsInADay = 86400;
            var DisplayInterval = 30; // seconds

            var TotalNumverOfVenues = data.SelectMany(x=> x.Venues).Distinct().Count();
            var AvailableSlots = SecondsInADay * data.SelectMany(x=> x.Venues).Distinct().Count() / DisplayInterval ; //assuming you didn't already have the count as a variable - will re-evaluate so don't use this for real!
            //var AvailableSlots = SecondsInADay * TotalNumverOfVenues / DisplayInterval ; //the better way - avoids recalculating count
            var SlotsNeeded = data.Sum(x => x.DailyImpressionsRequired);

        }
```

Comment: Hrm, things are now looking even more complicated. lol. I've got to disperse the Impressions throughout the available slots based on the availablity PER venue. Ah, I'm going crazy.